# How to bind with XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I want to bind a property of a class to a label content.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MyClass singletonInst = MyClass.Instance;
   //...
} 

public class MyClass
{
    public String MyValue
    {
        get { return "i'm the value"; }
    }
    //...
}
```

In My MainWindow.Xaml.cs I have my Window Name="DefaultWindow" and for my label I have..

```xml
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=DefaultWindow, Path=singletonInst.MyValue}" ...
```

But it doesn't work. Any Suggestions?

Comment: For the record if I move that MyValue property to the MainWindow class and change the Label Content Binding Path to just "MyValue" then it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only bind to properties and not fields.

```
public MyClass SingletonInst
{
    get { return MyClass.Instance;}
}
```